# Irreducible real curves on ${\mathbb C}P^1$ invariant under the finite group action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, plane-geometry, invariant-theory, real-algebraic-geometry, transformation-groups

Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of a Möbius group with a standart action on a *real algebraic variety* ${\mathbb C}{\mathbf P^1}.$

**How one can describe $G$-invariant irreducible real algebraic curves?**

Here by $G$-invariance i mean $G$-invariance as subsets of ${\mathbb C}{\mathbf P^1}$.

**What results are known in that direction?**

Some notes and examples:

1. If one drops irreducibility condition then the problem become not that interesting. Namely, one can take **any** curve $R.$ Then $\cup_{g\in G} gR$ is a reducible invariant real curve.
2. If one takes a group $({\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z})^2$ generated by inversion and conjugation, then the only conics invariant under that action are:

   a) coordinate axes $x=0, y=0;$

   b) unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$;

   c) continuous family of circles $x^2+y^2-cx+1=0,$ with non-empty curves for $c\in (-\infty, -2]\cup[2,+\infty).$
3. For the same action there exist an infinite family of invariant curves defined by even degree polynomials. 
   $$
   \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}\sum_{j=0}^{[\frac{i}{2}]}a_{ij}x^{i-2j}(x^2+y^2)^j(1+(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{n}{2}-i})
   $$
   It seems that nearly all of them are irreducible. I do not know any other invariant curves for that action, my hypothesis is that it is all of them.
   Main line of possible proof here is going to polar coordinates and examining properties of one-variable polynomials along the rays.